World's smallest Sudoku!
I present today, the world's smallest sudoku!
It is just 3x3 pixels in size, making it just a mere 216 bits of data 
It's currently right above! Pretending to be a full stop right here ↑

So my question is:
What colour does the middle box secretly contain?
(3 letters)

The image can look quite blurry when trying to zoom in, assuming due to image compression (same problem was experienced here - to look at it properly I recommend downloading and opening it using a pixel editor, Pixlr works well

I guessed the answer because there's not many 3 letter colour names.

@zooby Going through this list there are 5 three-letter colours.

@BeastlyGerbil I used my browser's developer tools to set the image's style to "width: 100%;image-rendering: crisp-edges;".

I ee what you did. The color is contained in the ASCII coding rather than be physical color of the box! +1

Let's blow up that image so we can get a better look at the colors:

 

This doesn't look much like a sudoku yet. But...

 the steganography tag is there...what if we look at the RGB values of each color?

It turns out that…

 each color's R, G, and B don't share any digits other than zero. For example, the top left box is #60EA47 in hex, which is (96, 234, 71) in RGB. And in fact, if we were to lay them out in a grid, with red on the top, green in the middle, and blue on the bottom:



 we can see that no digit (other than 0) repeats in a box, row, or column. In other words, now we've got a sudoku!



Solving the sudoku

 is pretty trivial ... for the most part. It turns out that there are two 2x2 squares that don't resolve:



 But hey, wait a minute ... that middle box now looks like it could be a different color if we reverse the process we did before!

Let's try that:

 (82, 69, 100) is this color:



 Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have a common name, nor does it resolve to a common three-letter color name. Maybe we need to try something different ... what about hex? This color's hex code is #524564, and we'll probably want to separate that out into 52, 45, 64.

Now what could that mean?

 I quickly thought of the ASCII table, and it turns out that all three of those letters resolve to letters when converted to ASCII characters. Namely, hex(52) is R, hex(45) is E, and hex(64) is d.

Therefore, the middle box secretly contains the color

 REd!


Huh? That’s not the image I got on my phone screen?

@PDT yeah I found that if you try to zoom in on the image it blurs it a lot so it's hard to get the right colors. I was able to eyedrop the colors using ms paint and then I rebuilt the image at a larger scale

Super speedy! Great job! @PDT zooming in on web won’t give great resolution, but if you download it and open it with a pixel editor it will have full resolution

Full stop, haha

@BeastlyGerbil well, he clearly misread one of the tags (see answer), and thought the intent was to write very fast.

((Lol I just now got what this ^ comment meant))
